# FlunetFTP and AlexFTPS unable to connect to Filezilla server under VPN

Tags: vpn, ftp, .net

Hi i am using FluentFTP to make my own little files and folders sync software. The problem is that the connect method of FluentFTP is not working when i try to connect to a Filezilla FTP Server under my private VPN but it works with other Filezilla FTP servers outside my VPN.

The problem happens only when using FluentFTP beacuse Filezilla Client is working fine and FreeFileSync is also working fine.

The exception i am getting is "Timed out while trying to connect."

I have also tried using the AlexFTPS c# library but the risult is same.

FluentFTP code:

Dim ftpClient As FluentFTP.FTPClient = New FluentFTP.FtpClient(tbFTPHostname.Text, 21, tbFTpUsername.Text, tbFTPPassword.Text)

If Not ftpClient.IsConnected Then ftpClient.Connect() End If

Dim aFtpClient As Client.FTPSClient = New Client.FTPSClient()

aFtpClient.Connect(ftpClient.Host, New NetworkCredential(ftpClient.Credentials.UserName, ftpClient.Credentials.Password), Client.ESSLSupportMode.ClearText)

Both of them are throwing "Connection timed out while conneting to server"... 
I have already tried putting FluentFTP in PASV mode but that works only sometimes and for a VERY short period of time.

It looks like FluentFTP is unable to reach the host due to some kind of routing put in place by the VPN. But then how can FileZilla Client reach the host and resolve the address?

Here is the Filezilla Client Log: https://pastebin.com/g8KJzAGu

```
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 0
Stato:  Connessione a 172.16.131.111:21...
Stato:  Connessione stabilita, in attesa del messaggio di benvenuto...
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   220-FileZilla Server 0.9.60 beta
Risposta:   220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
Risposta:   220 Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 2
Comando:    AUTH TLS
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   502 Explicit TLS authentication not allowed
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 3
Comando:    AUTH SSL
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   502 Explicit TLS authentication not allowed
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 3
Stato:  Server non sicuro, non supporta FTP su TLS.
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::SetAsyncRequestReply
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 5
Comando:    USER 0test0
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   331 Password required for 0test0
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 5
Comando:    PASS ******
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   230 Logged on
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 6
Comando:    SYST
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 6
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 7
Comando:    FEAT
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   211-Features:
Risposta:    MDTM
Risposta:    REST STREAM
Risposta:    SIZE
Risposta:    MLST type*;size*;modify*;
Risposta:    MLSD
Risposta:    UTF8
Risposta:    CLNT
Risposta:    MFMT
Risposta:    EPSV
Risposta:    EPRT
Risposta:   211 End
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 7
Stato:  Accesso effettuato
Trace:  Measured latency of 105 ms
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Reset(0) in state 14
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Stato:  Lettura elenco cartelle...
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 1
Comando:    PWD
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   257 "/" is current directory.
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Reset(0) in state 1
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult(0) in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::Send() in state 2
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 1
Comando:    TYPE I
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   200 Type set to I
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 2
Comando:    PASV
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   227 Entering Passive Mode (172,16,131,111,200,63)
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 4
Trace:  Binding data connection source IP to control connection source IP 172.16.114.179
Comando:    MLSD
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(2)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(2)
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Reset(2) in state 4
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult(2) in state 3
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(2)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(2)
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::Reset(2) in state 3
Errore: Non è stato possibile leggere il contenuto della cartella
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(2)
Stato:  Recupero elenco cartella di "/"...
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 4
Comando:    CDUP
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   200 CDUP successful. "/" is current directory.
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 5
Comando:    PWD
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   257 "/" is current directory.
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Reset(0) in state 5
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult(0) in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::Send() in state 2
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 2
Comando:    PASV
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   227 Entering Passive Mode (172,16,131,111,228,7)
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 4
Trace:  Binding data connection source IP to control connection source IP 172.16.114.179
Comando:    MLSD
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnConnect
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 5
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20180320091918; AUDIO_BACKUP
Elenco: type=file;modify=20161117072528;size=16384; bar_off.exe
Elenco: type=file;modify=20161117072528;size=16384; bar_on.exe
Elenco: type=file;modify=20161027095403;size=59904; ExecURL.exe
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20190507083658; FileSync_SERVER
Elenco: type=file;modify=20170905142400;size=85900; FullScreen.jpg
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20180320123956; mdb
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20190522143026; musica
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20190626163336; musica64
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20111005104116; ORARI
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20190613144142; pdvconfig
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20190705140301; pdvselect
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20190507144335; playlist
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20190705140003; rubriche
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20190705140301; spotcanale
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20180128030201; spotcop
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20190705140301; spotnazionali
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20181024131425; TASTI
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20190705131851; test
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20120525131851; VNC PDV
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20190416073300;size=16633; VsRadioPlayer.ini
Trace:  CTransferSocket::TransferEnd(1)
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   226 Successfully transferred "/"
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 8
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::TransferEnd()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Reset(0) in state 8
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult(0) in state 3
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::Reset(0) in state 3
Stato:  Elenco cartella di "/" completato
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Stato:  Recupero elenco cartella di "/AUDIO_BACKUP"...
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 4
Comando:    CWD AUDIO_BACKUP
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   250 CWD successful. "/AUDIO_BACKUP" is current directory.
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 5
Comando:    PWD
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   257 "/AUDIO_BACKUP" is current directory.
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Reset(0) in state 5
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult(0) in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::Send() in state 2
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 2
Comando:    PASV
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   227 Entering Passive Mode (172,16,131,111,230,34)
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 4
Trace:  Binding data connection source IP to control connection source IP 172.16.114.179
Comando:    MLSD
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnConnect
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/AUDIO_BACKUP"
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 5
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728152318;size=3661809; 360_Sandra.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728152331;size=4331457; Aerosmith - I Don t Want to Miss a Thing.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728152426;size=3341183; AlessandraAmoroso_Ciao.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728152436;size=3190356; AlexBritti_7000Caffe.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728152628;size=6009472; All Saints - Never Ever.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728152553;size=3773782; Anjulie_Rain.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728152656;size=3065960; AntonioMaggio_Stanco.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728152739;size=3498647; BabyK_Killer.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728152804;size=3381345; Backstreet Boys - Inconsolable.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728152905;size=4224040; BenHarper_DiamondsOnTheInside.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728152915;size=3463200; BenWestbeech_SomethingForTheWeekend.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728153012;size=3328173; Beyonce - Sweet Dreams.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728153033;size=3834825; Biagio Antonacci ft Leona Lewis - Inaspettata.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728153127;size=3681265; Blink182_IMissYou.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728153152;size=3899266; Bran Van 3000 - Drinking In LA.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728153226;size=2879268; BrunoMars_Treasure.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728153259;size=3300983; Caro Emerald e Giuliano Palma - Vivere riviera life.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728153339;size=3596589; Cesare Cremonini - Deve essere così.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728153356;size=2813265; CharliXCX_BoomClap.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728153451;size=3525969; ChristinaAguilera_GenieInABottle.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728153511;size=3705563; ClubDogo_Pes.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728153602;size=3498634; CraigDavid_ AllTheWay.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728153631;size=3922008; DavidBowie_WhereAreWeNow.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728153714;size=3569869; DeathCabforCutie_MeetMeOntheEquinox.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728153813;size=5057386; Diana Ross - Im Coming Out.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728153827;size=3569004; Dolcenera - Il Mio Amore Unico.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728153944;size=4514009; Earth Wind  Fire - Boogie Wonderland.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728153925;size=2854820; ElizaDoolittle_WasteOfTime.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728154107;size=4089984; EmmaLouise_Boy.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728154035;size=3425325; Emma_LaMiaCitta.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728154135;size=2919407; Empire Of The Sun - Walking On A Dream.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150728154202;size=3995837; EnriqueIglesias_Bailando.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729163632;size=3864451; FabiSilvestriGazze_CanzoneDiAnna.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729163636;size=4031561; FrancescaMichielin_Distratto.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729163743;size=3494080; Francesco Renga - Regina Triste.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729163755;size=3890365; FrancescoSarcina_OdioLeStelle.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729163845;size=3017716; Fugees - Killing Me Softly.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729163905;size=3460752; Gianna Nannini - Maledetto Ciao.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729163945;size=2959823; Giorgia_LaMiaStanza.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729164012;size=3252799; GiulianoPalma_ComeIeri.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729164106;size=4000759; Gotye_SomebodyThatIUsedToKnow.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729164133;size=4000438; GymClassHeroesfeatAdamLevine_StereoHearts.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729164211;size=3179829; ImagineDragons_IBetMyLife.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729164254;size=3982674; Irene Grandi - In Vacanza Da una Vita.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729164306;size=2704664; Jackson 5 - I want you back.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729164400;size=3276741; Jason Derulo - Dont wanna go home.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729164426;size=3937830; JasonMraz_LoveSomeone.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729164500;size=2959619; Jennifer Lopez - Do It Well.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729164537;size=3516446; JohnLegend_Tonight.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729164617;size=3746178; JossStone_SuperDuperLove.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729164655;size=3808866; Jovanotti - Il piu grande spettacolo dopo il big bang.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729164710;size=2678333; Kate Nash - Pumpkin soup.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729164755;size=2970068; Katie Melua - Nine Million Bicycles.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729164819;size=3366361; KatyPerry_ThisIsHowWeDo.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150729164847;size=3890723; Kid Rock ft Mary J Blige - Care.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731155256;size=4338614; LadyGaga_MarryTheNight.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731155246;size=3810091; LauraPausini_Benvenuto.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731155410;size=4144006; Ligabue - Il meglio deve ancora venire.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731155402;size=3226695; Lily Allen - The Fear.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731155532;size=4440339; Litfiba - Spirito.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731155524;size=3659557; Luca Carboni - Fare Le Valigie.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731155643;size=3883727; Luna Pop - Resta Con Me.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731155654;size=4016299; Madonna_PapaDontPreach.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731155757;size=3666297; MarcoMengoni_NonPasserai.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731155801;size=3342307; MarlonRoudette_WhenTheBeatDropsOut.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731155906;size=3368070; Maroon 5 - Moves Like Jagger feat Christin.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731155928;size=4283389; Max Gazze - Una Musica Puo Fare.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731160032;size=4162297; MichaelJackson_APlaceWithNoName.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731160036;size=3361696; Mika - Happy Ending.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731160136;size=3185869; Morcheeba_BeYourself.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731160146;size=3475829; Neffa_LaNotte.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731160254;size=3795059; Negrita_IlGioco.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731160302;size=3730378; Nek - E Da Qui.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731160405;size=3523611; Nesli_EUnaVita.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731160420;size=3810015; NeYo - Miss Independent.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150731160515;size=3667777; Nomadi_ComeVaLaVita.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803164221;size=3753696; OneRepublic_LoveRunsOut.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803164213;size=3332575; OwlCity_GoodTime.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803164331;size=3821493; Passenger_LetHerGo.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803164333;size=3539704; PhilCollins_Sussudio.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803164452;size=3957384; Pink_Try.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803164453;size=3963557; Police - Message In A Bottle.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803164603;size=3483740; Pussycat Dolls - Jai Ho.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803164619;size=4184130; Red Hot Chili Peppers - Under the Bridge.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803164708;size=3219589; Rihanna - Te Amo.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803164731;size=3525118; Rio - Sei Quella Per Me.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803164837;size=4271484; Rolling Stones - Angie.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803164851;size=3585658; RonanKeating_LifeIsARollercoaster.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803164954;size=4079640; Samuele Bersani - Spaccacuore.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803165004;size=3536546; Sia_Chandelier.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803165058;size=3184481; Simple Plan - Welcome To My Life.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803165116;size=3322408; Take That - Shine.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803165154;size=2622744; Temptations - My girl.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803165213;size=2874098; TheRomantics_WhatILikeAboutYou.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803165322;size=4326346; Tiromancino - Due Destini.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803165354;size=4976690; Verve - Bitter Sweet Symphony.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803165431;size=3243413; Vibrazioni - Dedicato A Te.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803165534;size=4189161; VinicioCapossela_CheCosseLamor.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803165605;size=4632433; YoussouNDour_7Seconds.mp3
Elenco: type=file;modify=20150803165626;size=3071105; Zucchero - X colpa di chi.mp3
Trace:  CTransferSocket::TransferEnd(1)
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   226 Successfully transferred "/AUDIO_BACKUP"
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 8
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::TransferEnd()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Reset(0) in state 8
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult(0) in state 3
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::Reset(0) in state 3
Stato:  Elenco cartella di "/AUDIO_BACKUP" completato
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Stato:  Recupero elenco cartella di "/spotcanale"...
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 2
Comando:    CWD /
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   250 CWD successful. "/" is current directory.
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 3
Comando:    PWD
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   257 "/" is current directory.
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 3
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 4
Comando:    CWD spotcanale
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   250 CWD successful. "/spotcanale" is current directory.
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 5
Comando:    PWD
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   257 "/spotcanale" is current directory.
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Reset(0) in state 5
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult(0) in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::Send() in state 2
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 2
Comando:    PASV
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   227 Entering Passive Mode (172,16,131,111,194,97)
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 4
Trace:  Binding data connection source IP to control connection source IP 172.16.114.179
Comando:    MLSD
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnConnect
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/spotcanale"
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 5
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Trace:  CTransferSocket::TransferEnd(1)
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::TransferEnd()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   226 Successfully transferred "/spotcanale"
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 7
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Reset(0) in state 7
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult(0) in state 3
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20190610160441; city
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20190610160441; conad
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20190610160441; leclerc
Elenco: type=dir;modify=20190610160441; superstore
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::Reset(0) in state 3
Stato:  Elenco cartella di "/spotcanale" completato
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
Stato:  Recupero elenco cartella di "/spotcanale/city"...
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpListOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 4
Comando:    CWD city
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Risposta:   250 CWD successful. "/spotcanale/city" is current directory.
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 5
```

Comment: FTP is a terrible protocol too use unless you have a connectivity between both systems where these can communicate without any kind of obstruction (firewalls, NAT...) with each other and also use IP address in their PORT/PASV commands which can be accessed from the peer. It is not clear what happens in your case (too much dumped log, too few details) but I expect that there are either some firewall rules or the use of wrong IP addresses hindering the communication.

Comment: To me it looks like the my application is unable to resolve the real address of the machine inside the vpn... i am trying to understand how Filezilla Client is able to resolve the address correctly. I think i'lll have to use wireshark or else debug filezilla client...